# Why does coord_map produce a weird output?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a world map using `ggplot`. My code is in my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/38666a7fecab76f986b4). The output is correct when I don't use `coord_map` but very strange when I use `coord_map` :

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(fill = x)) +
geom_map(aes(map_id = id), map =world.ggmap, color = "white") +
expand_limits(x = world.ggmap$long, y = world.ggmap$lat) +
theme_tufte() + 
coord_map()
```

[image: map with <code>coord_map</code>]

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(fill = x)) +
geom_map(aes(map_id = id), map =world.ggmap, color = "white") +
expand_limits(x = world.ggmap$long, y = world.ggmap$lat) +
theme_tufte()
```

[image]

I've got the same error when I use data from the maps package :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
world <- map_data("world")
ggplot() + 
geom_map( data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, map_id = region),colour="white", fill="grey10", map = world ) + 
coord_map()
```

[image]

Does anyone has an answer ?

Comment: There is another related question with another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360830/map-in-ggplot2-visualization-displaying-bug/30463740#30463740

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem before, due to longitude values outside the range  [-180,180]. In your example the data do not have this problem but my trick seems to work also here. In my case I just used 'xlim' to exclude the problematic data.

This solution seems to work in your case also (I used the code from your gist):

```
map+coord_map(xlim=c(-180,180))
```

It produces the following map:

[image]

There is still a problem with Antarctica, you can also consider clipping it too if you don't need this area:

```
map+coord_map(xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-60, 90))
```

[image]

Comment: I still have a problem with the Greenland with the default world map : library(ggplot2)
library(maps) 
world <- map_data("world")
ggplot() +   geom_map( data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, map_id = region), colour="white", fill="grey10", map = world ) + coord_map(xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-60, 90))

Comment: In the documentation of `mapproject` says that: _Points deemed unprojectable (such as north of 80 degrees latitude in the Mercator projection) are returned as NA._ I suppose this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `wrld_simpl` from `maptools` instead, but it retains issues with Antarctica.

```
require(maptools)
require(ggmap)

md <- map_data("world2")
data(wrld_simpl)
ggplot(wrld_simpl, aes(group = group, x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_map() +
  coord_map()
```

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that is quite late but the same problem is still happening in ggplot.

If you're trying to zoom-in use the following approach.

```
ggplot()+...+xlim(c(-100, -25))+ ylim(c(-60, 20))
```

Good luck!