# Map in ggplot2 visualization/displaying bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As you can see below, there is a weird displaying problem on the maps I made using ggplots. The same problem seems to happen with any projection.

[image]

Here is the code:
Only the packages `maps` and `ggplot2` are needed

```
  mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="black")
    ggplot() + mapWorld +
      coord_map("mercator") +
      ylim(-90,90)
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in the data. Maybe in the ordering, maybe not. When I run `summary(mapWorld$data)` looks like longitude is coded from -179 to 190... I would expect -180 to 180

Comment: I had not thought of that. I will try with other data. Thanks !

Comment: I can replicate your problem, but the examples at the bottom of `?border` work just fine for me. I'm 99% sure it's a data issue rather than a ggplot issue.

Comment: examples at the bottom of `?borders` work fine for me too. That's weird since some peoples use `borders("world", ...)` without any mention of this problem

Comment: Adding `+coord_equal` to the plot appears to fix the problem. But I am not posting this as an answer because I am not certain it is a solution per se i.e. Shouldn't the projection specification in `coord_map()` suffice ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem is caused by the polygons that cross the 0 coordinate, the place in which the world merges. R dont knows how to close those polygons and projects them all around the world.

This method recreates the polygons and prevents them from crossing the 0 coordinate (xlim and ylim). It works with any kind of projection.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(PBSmapping)
require(data.table)

mapWorld <- map_data("world")
setnames(mapWorld, c("X","Y","PID","POS","region","subregion"))
worldmap = clipPolys(mapWorld, xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim, keepExtra=TRUE)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = mapWorld, aes(X,Y,group=PID))
```

Comment: This throws me the following error: `Error in .clip(polys, xlim, ylim, isPolygons = TRUE, keepExtra) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Answer (score 1):

why you need to use?

```
ggplot() + mapWorld +
  coord_map("mercator") +
  ylim(-90,90)
```

if u use just

```
ggplot() + mapWorld
```

It works perfectly