# Unwanted Horizontal Lines in Map Projection in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

A few lines of code to expose my problem. When I work with a map of
the world and I introduce a projection, I always end up with some
weird looking horizontal lines.
Please have a look at
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/coord_map

from where I take the example for New Zeland

```
library(ggplot2)

nz <- map_data("nz")
# Prepare a map of NZ
nzmap <- ggplot(nz, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black")

# Plot it in cartesian coordinates
nzmap
# With correct mercator projection
nzmap + coord_map()
```

which works beautifully. Now let us do the same with the world

```
world <- map_data("world")
# Prepare a map of the world
worldmap <- ggplot(world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon(fill = "white", colour = "black")

# Plot it in cartesian coordinates
worldmap

##but the following is a disaster!
# With correct mercator projection
worldmap + coord_map()
```

[image]
I see this issue of the horizontal lines with a projection has been
going on for quite a while, but I was able to find only seasoned posts
and I had assumed this was fixed long ago.
Please find below my sessionInfo.
Is there any solution to this? Is it still an open bug?

Comment: Please post an image. Also, can't use https:// with that link because its certificate is invalid.

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1104) it's a known problem, but there are no plans to fix it as the creators preferred to move on to better sources of data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem in ggplot, but happily it is easily fixed:

`worldmap + coord_map(xlim=c(-180,180))`

produces[image: this]

solution from: [Why does coord_map produce a weird output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652711/why-does-coord-map-produce-a-weird-output)