# recenter projections over Pacific with sf package

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'm trying to create projected maps (Robinson in the example below) centered on the Pacific, but I'm getting strange unwanted horizontal lines. The st_bbox() solution doesn't seem to help

```
rm(list=ls())
library(giscoR)
library(rworldmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

crsLONGLAT <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
crsrobin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Using giscoR
world_sf <- gisco_get_countries(resolution = 10)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_sf)

world_robinson <- st_transform(world_sf, 
                               crs = crsrobin) ## looks great
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_robinson) ## looks great

## Pacific centered Robinson
crsrobin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=-180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
world_robinson <- st_transform(world_sf, 
                               crs = crsrobin) ## horizontal artifacts

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_robinson) ## horizontal artifacts
```

I get the same result with different map data

```
world_sp <- fortify(getMap())
world_sf <- world_sp %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = crsLONGLAT, row.names="group") %>%
  group_by(group) %>% summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")
```

This bbox hack looks fine for coordinates, but doesn't work with the projection

```
world_box <- st_cast(st_combine(st_as_sf(data.frame("x"=c(-180, -180, 180, 180),"y"=c(90, -90, -90, 90)),coords = c("x","y"), crs=crsLONGLAT)),"POLYGON")
world_box_robin <- st_transform(world_box, crs=crsrobin)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data=world_box) + geom_sf(data=world_sf)

b <- st_bbox(world_box)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=world_sf) +
  coord_sf(crs = crsLONGLAT, xlim = c(b["xmin"], b["xmax"]), ylim = c(b["ymin"], b["ymax"]))


ggplot()+ geom_sf(data=world_box_robin)  + geom_sf(data=world_robinson) 


b <- st_bbox(world_box_robin)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=world_robinson) + 
  coord_sf(crs = crsrobin, xlim = c(b["xmin"], b["xmax"]), ylim = c(b["ymin"], b["ymax"]))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652711/why-does-coord-map-produce-a-weird-output

Comment: Thanks. That's the older solution for ggplot without sf and geom_sf(). It's my fallback. But I'm looking for something that works with sf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for `st_break_antimeridian`:

```
crsrobin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=-180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

world_robinson2 <- world_sf %>%
  st_break_antimeridian(lon_0 = 180) %>% # insert this before transformation
                                         # (& ignore the warning)
  st_transform(crs = crsrobin)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_robinson2)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! For my needs, the warning about spherical geometry (s2) is important only because st_area() and st_distance will be inaccurate for the Pacific-centered map even with an equal-area projections such as "+proj=eqearth"